# jakarta.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.app.user.User with id 1

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a User, and ConfirmationToken Entity Classes, the RegistrationController Class that contains the register() POST method, and token confirm() GET method to confirm the token.

Both classes are related by @OneToMany relationship

Everything worked fine earlier until recently when I was implementing unrelated classes. The user registration and email with the token worked fine.
But the confirm() method return

```
jakarta.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.affiantor.user.User with id 1
```

**Below is the ConfirmationToken Entity Class**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class ConfirmationToken {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "confirmation_token_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "confirmation_token_id",
            sequenceName = "confirmation_token_id",
            allocationSize = 1)

    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String token;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    private LocalDateTime confirmedAt;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime expiresAt;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false,
            name = "user_id")
    private User user;

public ConfirmationToken(String token,
                             LocalDateTime createdAt,
                             LocalDateTime expiresAt,
                             User user) {
        this.token = token;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.expiresAt = expiresAt;
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

**ConfirmationTokenService class**

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ConfirmationTokenService {


    private final ConfirmationTokenRepository confirmationTokenRepository;

    public void saveConfirmationToken(ConfirmationToken token){
        confirmationTokenRepository.save (token);
    }

    public Optional<ConfirmationToken> getToken(String token){
        return confirmationTokenRepository.findByToken (token);
    }

    public void setConfirmedAt(String token){
       confirmationTokenRepository.updateConfirmedAt(
                token, LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}
```

**ConfirmationTokenRepository class**

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Qualifier("ConfirmationToken")
public interface ConfirmationTokenRepository extends JpaRepository<ConfirmationToken, Long> {

    Optional<ConfirmationToken>findByToken(String token);

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE ConfirmationToken c " +
            "SET c.confirmedAt = ?2 " +
            "WHERE c.token = ?1 ")
    void updateConfirmedAt(String token,
                        LocalDateTime confirmedAt);


}
```

**The User Entity class**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@ToString
@Entity(name="User")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "user_login_id",
            sequenceName = "user_login_id",
            allocationSize = 1
    )

    /**
     * Registration table fields Start here
     */
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 30, nullable = false, unique = true)
    @NotNull(message = "EMAIL field can not be null")
    @NotEmpty(message = "EMAIL field can not be empty")
    private String email;

    @Column(length = 80, nullable = false)
    @NotNull(message = "PASSWORD can not be null")
    @NotEmpty(message = "PASSWORD field can not be empty")
    private String password;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Collection<ConfirmationToken> confirmationToken;
    

   //Other user fields, constructors, etc.

    public Collection<ConfirmationToken> getConfirmationToken() {
        return confirmationToken;
    }

    public void setConfirmationToken(Collection<ConfirmationToken> confirmationToken) {
        this.confirmationToken = confirmationToken;
    }
```

**RegistrationService Class**

```
@Transactional
        public String confirmToken (String token){
            var confirmationToken = confirmationTokenService
                    .getToken (token)
                    .orElseThrow (() ->
                            new IllegalStateException ("Token not found"));

            if (confirmationToken.getConfirmedAt () != null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException ("Email already confirmed");
            }

            LocalDateTime expiredAt = confirmationToken.getExpiresAt ();
            if (expiredAt.isBefore (LocalDateTime.now ())) {
                throw new IllegalStateException ("Token expired, please contact the support department to activate your account.");
            }

            confirmationTokenService.setConfirmedAt (token);
            userService.activateUserAccount (
                    confirmationToken.getUser ().getEmail ());
            return "Email confirmed, you can now login using your email and the password provided during registration.";
        }
```

**ConfirmationService Class**

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ConfirmationTokenService {


    private final ConfirmationTokenRepository confirmationTokenRepository;

    public void saveConfirmationToken(ConfirmationToken token){
        confirmationTokenRepository.save (token);
    }

    public Optional<ConfirmationToken> getToken(String token){
        return confirmationTokenRepository.findByToken (token);
    }

    public void setConfirmedAt(String token){
       confirmationTokenRepository.updateConfirmedAt(
                token, LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}
```

**RegisterController Class**

```
@PostMapping(path = "register" , consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String register(@RequestBody RegistrationRequest request){
        return registrationService.registerUser (request);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "confirm")
    public String confirm(@RequestParam("token") String token){

        return registrationService.confirmToken (token);
    }
```

**STACK TRACE**

```
2023-07-21T16:33:03.645+02:00 ERROR 28900 --- [nio-8281-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: jakarta.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.affiantor.user.User with id 1] with root cause

jakarta.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.affiantor.user.User with id 1
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.checkTargetState(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.5.Final.jar:6.2.5.Final]
    at com.affiantor.user.User$HibernateProxy$8YnXCzWQ.getEmail(Unknown Source) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.affiantor.registration.RegistrationService.confirmToken(RegistrationService.java:84) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391) ~[spring-tx-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at com.affiantor.registration.RegistrationService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.confirmToken(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.affiantor.registration.RegistrationController.confirm(RegistrationController.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:527) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at com.affiantor.security.config.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:66) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$FilterObservation$SimpleFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:426) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$1(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:287) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator.lambda$wrapSecured$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:187) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:174) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:187) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:174) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:187) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:174) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:187) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:174) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:187) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:174) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:187) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:174) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.RequestMatcherRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestMatcherRedirectFilter.java:67) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:187) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:174) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:187) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:174) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:187) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:174) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:187) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:174) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:187) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:174) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:187) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:270) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:171) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:135) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M5.jar:11.0.0-M5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Please any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks

I tried to confirm the registration token and was expecting a return below

```
"Email confirmed, you can now login using your email and the password provided during registration."
```